# Test set and train set for each fold in Caret cross validation

Tags: r, random-forest, cross-validation, r-caret

I tried to understand the 5 fold cross validation algorithm in Caret package but I could not find out how to get train set and test set for each fold and I also could not find this from the similar suggested questions. Imagine if I want to do cross validation by random forest method, I do the following:

```
set.seed(12)
train_control <- trainControl(method="cv", number=5,savePredictions = TRUE)
rfmodel <- train(Species~., data=iris, trControl=train_control, method="rf")
first_holdout <- subset(rfmodel$pred, Resample == "Fold1")
str(first_holdout)
'data.frame':   90 obs. of  5 variables:
$ pred    : Factor w/ 3 levels "setosa","versicolor",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1     
$ obs     : Factor w/ 3 levels "setosa","versicolor",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
$ rowIndex: int  2 3 9 11 25 29 35 36 41 50 ...
$ mtry    : num  2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
$ Resample: chr  "Fold1" "Fold1" "Fold1" "Fold1" ...
```

Are these 90 observations in Fold1 used as training set? If yes then where is the test set for this fold?

Comment: No need to do it manually. Check `str(rfModel)` You will find it there in `index` and `indexOut` having samples roow indexthat went to train and hold out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 str(rfmodel)
```

Model performed stores everything in the below form. `control` in the below stores the indexes for samples that went to Train and respective hold outs in `index` and `indexOut`.

```
 names(rfmodel)
 #  [1] "method"       "modelInfo"    "modelType"    "results"      "pred"        
 #  [6] "bestTune"     "call"         "dots"         "metric"       "control"     
 # [11] "finalModel"   "preProcess"   "trainingData" "resample"     "resampledCM" 
 # [16] "perfNames"    "maximize"     "yLimits"      "times"        "levels"      
 # [21] "terms"        "coefnames"    "xlevels"
```

**Path to indexes of Train and Hold Out samples**

```
 # Indexes of Hold Out Sets
 rfmodel$control$indexOut

 # Indexes of Train Sets for above hold outs
 rfmodel$control$index
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, so the list of accuracy in  rfmodel$resample is the accuracy of predictions in each fold done on the hold-out samples?

Comment: Yes. That is True. Those woudl be the results of hold out predictions.

Comment: Always do `str()` and `names()` on model you perform to see how and what it has stored and how we can access information from model created or prediction performed. So make use of these functions to help you learn.