# How train data manually per fold with k-fold CV in R?

Tags: r, machine-learning, cross-validation, r-caret

I have the following code segment which works for me and I get the model result:

```
library(base)
library(caret)
library(tidyverse)

dataset <- read_csv("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/dmpe/bfe07a29c7fc1e3a70d0522956d8e4a9/raw/7ea71f7432302bb78e58348fede926142ade6992/pima-indians-diabetes.csv", col_names=FALSE)
X = dataset[, 1:8]
Y = as.factor(ifelse(dataset$X9 == 1, 'diabetes', 'nondiabetes'))

set.seed(88)

nfolds <- 3
cvIndex <- createFolds(Y, nfolds, returnTrain = T)

fit.control <- trainControl(method="cv",
                            index=cvIndex,
                            number=nfolds,
                            classProbs=TRUE,
                            savePredictions=TRUE,
                            verboseIter=TRUE,
                            summaryFunction=twoClassSummary,
                            allowParallel=FALSE)

model <- caret::train(X, Y,
                      method = "svmLinear",
                      trControl = fit.control,
                      preProcess=c("center","scale"),
                      tuneLength=10)
```

Using this I can access the final model as `model$finalModel`, however, in this case instead of having one final model, I actually want to have 3 models as I have 3-fold. So, I want to get the trained model after first fold, then after second fold and lastly after the third fold, which corresponds to the actual final model. Any ideas how to achieve this in R? Please note that usage of `caret` is not strict, if you can do it with `mlr` that's also welcomed.

Comment: Maybe this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46876271/test-set-and-train-set-for-each-fold-in-caret-cross-validation or this: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/114168/how-to-get-sub-training-and-sub-test-from-cross-validation-in-caret

Comment: Are you looking to do ensembling or something? What's the ultimate aim?

Comment: @NelsonGon I saw the question, it seems to give a way to access indexes, however I want models. The scenario is that I need to plot PDP, and I'm asked to do that k times, so after each fold. Hence, I want to get the trained model after first fold, plot PDP, then after second fold, plot PDP, and so on.

Comment: `mlr` package allows for this functionality, [check it out](https://mlr.mlr-org.com/reference/resample.html) - models argument.

Comment: @missuse I tried to look at mlr, but couldn’t understand how this is done, can you please provide minimal code for how this will be in m scenario?

Comment: @terett yes, will post it in a few hours. In the mean time you can take a look at their [tutorials](https://mlr.mlr-org.com/index.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an approach using mlr package:

```
library(mlr)
library(base)
library(tidyverse)

dataset <- read_csv("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/dmpe/bfe07a29c7fc1e3a70d0522956d8e4a9/raw/7ea71f7432302bb78e58348fede926142ade6992/pima-indians-diabetes.csv", col_names=FALSE)
X = dataset[, 1:8]
Y = as.factor(ifelse(dataset$X9 == 1, 'diabetes', 'nondiabetes'))
```

create a mlr task:

```
mlr_task <-  makeClassifTask(data = data.frame(X, Y),
                             target = "Y",
                             positive = "diabetes")
```

define the resampling:

```
set.seed(7)

cv3 <- makeResampleInstance(makeResampleDesc("CV", iters = 3),
                            task = mlr_task)
```

define the type of hyper parameter search

```
ctrl <- makeTuneControlRandom(maxit = 10L)
```

define a learner

```
lrn <- makeLearner("classif.ksvm", predict.type = "prob")
```

optionally check learner parameters to see which ones to tune

```
mlr::getLearnerParamSet(lrn)
```

define search space (vanilladot is linear kernel in kernlab package which is called internally for "classif.ksvm"). More info on integrated learners in mlr: https://mlr.mlr-org.com/articles/tutorial/integrated_learners.html

```
ps <- makeParamSet(makeDiscreteParam("kernel", "vanilladot"),
                   makeNumericParam("C", lower = 2e-6, upper = 2e-6))
```

tune hyper parameters. I just set some random measures, the first one listed is used to evaluate the performance, the others are there just for show.

```
res <- tuneParams(lrn,
                  mlr_task,
                  cv3,
                  measures = list(auc, bac, f1),
                  par.set = ps,
                  control = ctrl)
```

set optimal hyper parameters to a learner

```
lrn <- setHyperPars(lrn, par.vals = res$x)
```

resample with `models = TRUE`

```
rsmpls <- resample(lrn,
                   mlr_task,
                   cv3,
                   measures = list(auc, bac, f1),
                   models = TRUE)
```

models are in

```
rsmpls$models[[1]]$learner.model  
rsmpls$models[[2]]$learner.model  
rsmpls$models[[3]]$learner.model
```

What this does is it first tunes the hyper parameters and then performs another set of cross validation with tuned parameters on the same folds.

an alternative and in my opinion a better approach is to pick hyper parameters in the inner folds of nested cross validation and evaluate on the outer folds keeping outer fold models to fiddle with.

```
lrn <- makeLearner("classif.ksvm", predict.type = "prob")
```

define an inner resampling strategy

```
cv3_inner <- makeResampleDesc("CV", iters = 3)
```

create a tune wrapper - define what happens in inner cross validation loop

```
lrn <- makeTuneWrapper(lrn,
                       resampling = cv3_inner,
                       measures = list(auc, bac, f1),
                       par.set = ps,
                       control = ctrl)
```

perform outer cross validation

```
rsmpls <- resample(lrn,
                   mlr_task,
                   cv3,
                   measures = list(auc, bac, f1),
                   models = TRUE)
```

This performs three fold CV in the outer loop, in each training instance another, three fold CV is performed to tune the hyper parameters and a model is fit on the whole training instance with optimal hyper parameters, these models are evaluated on the outer loop test instances. This is done to reduce evaluation bias. See also: https://mlr.mlr-org.com/articles/tutorial/nested_resampling.html

Comment: One quick question, with `caret` I usually create two partitions of the data, one training set and one testing set, which normally looks like this: `index <- createDataPartition(dataset$Y,
                               p=0.8,
                               list=FALSE,
                               time=1)
 
  dataset_train <- dataset[index,]
  dataset_test <- dataset[-index,]`, and then use `dataset_train` for training the model, and `dataset_test` for actually testing how well the model is performing. In your example I see you use whole dataset, how can I divide like this with `mlr`?

Comment: Why not just use the `caret` method? In all honesty it is easier to use than anything I know of in mlr.

Comment: I just want to get the 3 models for each fold. And I couldn't find a way to do that in `caret`, and your beautiful answer seems to give a way for it.

Comment: I meant why not just use `createDataPartition` from caret and the rest from `mlr`? A way to do a train/test split in mlr would be: `hold <- makeResampleInstance(makeResampleDesc("Holdout", split = 2/3),
                             task = mlr_task)`  and then subset based on `hold$train.inds`/ `hold$test.inds`. Btw check this out also: https://mlr.mlr-org.com/articles/tutorial/partial_dependence.html since you mentioned you need PDP.

Comment: @missue But, I won't be able to use this model's as input for example to `Predictor$new` function of `iml`. It seems to only accept fully trained model.

Comment: @terett Since `iml::Predictor$new` likes `mlr` models you can pass `rsmpls$models[[1]]` as model, if you pass  `rsmpls$models[[1]]$learner.model` you are in fact passing a `kernlab` model so you should use `kernlab::predict` as the prediction function. In short: `mdl <- Predictor$new(model =  rsmpls$models[[1]], data = X, y = Y)` and then `mdl$predict(X)` works.

Comment: Thanks, makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

The train function in caret streamlines model evaluation and training
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/caret/vignettes/caret.html

"evaluate, using resampling, the effect of model tuning parameters on performance
choose the ``optimal’’ model across these parameters
estimate model performance from a training set"

So, the model that it gives is the optimal final model. 
There is no reason to use the models trained on each fold. I'm not aware of how to do this in R

Comment: "There is no reason to want the models trained on each fold.", this is broad overstatement. Everyone has a different scenario, and for research purposes it is useful to have that.

Comment: The way I stated that was naive, I don't believe there is a way to get the models trained on each fold

Answer (score 0):

Not a caret nor machine learning expert, but why not  just train the model on a random sample and store the result in a list?

```
   data <- read_csv("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/dmpe/bfe07a29c7fc1e3a70d0522956d8e4a9/raw/7ea71f7432302bb78e58348fede926142ade6992/pima-indians-diabetes.csv", col_names=FALSE)

    train_multiple_models <- function(data, kfolds) {
        resultlist <- list()
        for(i in 1:kfolds) {

            sample <- sample.int(n = nrow(data), size = floor(.75*nrow(data)), replace = F)
            train <- data[sample, ]

            X = train[, 1:8]
            Y = as.factor(ifelse(train$X9 == 1, 'diabetes', 'nondiabetes'))

            model <- caret::train(X, Y,
                                  method = "svmLinear",
                                  preProcess=c("center","scale"),
                                  tuneLength=10)
            resultlist[[i]] <- model
        }
        return(resultlist)
    }

    result <- train_multiple_models(data, kfolds = 3)


    > result[[1]]$finalModel
    Support Vector Machine object of class "ksvm" 

    SV type: C-svc  (classification) 
     parameter : cost C = 1 

    Linear (vanilla) kernel function. 

    Number of Support Vectors : 307 

    Objective Function Value : -302.065 
    Training error : 0.230903
```